# using firebase in project the datais not getting inserted into firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have given the insert code of firebase, but the data is not getting inserted into firebase database.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newregistration);
        UserName = findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        Empid = findViewById(R.id.Empid);
        phoneno = findViewById(R.id.Phoneno);
        Emailid = findViewById(R.id.Emailid);
        Newpassword = findViewById(R.id.newpassword);
        btn_back = findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        btnreg = findViewById(R.id.btnreg);
        member= new Member();
        reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");
        reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                    maxid=(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        btnreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            reff.child(String.valueOf(maxid+1)).setValue(member);
                member.setUserName(UserName.getText().toString().trim());
                member.setEmailid(Emailid.getText().toString().trim());
                member.setEmpid(Empid.getText().toString().trim());
                member.setPhoneno(phoneno.getText().toString().trim());
              member.setNewpassword(Newpassword.getText().toString().trim());
                Toast.makeText(Newregistration.this,"Data Inserted Succesfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(Newregistration.this, LoginActivity.class));

            }
        });

        btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Newregistration.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

The app gets crashed when we hit register and the expected result should insert in to firebase realtime database.

Comment: If you ready to use firestore then I will help you to make it?

Comment: but my idea was to insert in to firebase real time DB and can u plz tell me the difference between firebase and firestore

Comment: What is the error that you get? Please add it to your question and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: bro firestore is part of firebase. Firebase have two database and both are for realtime and one is firebase and second one is firestore with same function and feature but there is only one difference that is  UI of firestore and UI of firebase

Comment: To learn about the different database options within Firebase, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore

Answer (score 0):

1. You should post the logcat to show the error as well
2. You called `setValue(member)` before actually putting values into member

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete 
com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 80133 > 65536) this are the errors which comes when i rebuild